# Spring Data Error with specific object

Tags: spring-data

I have the following repository:

```
public interface ICredCardRepository extends JpaRepository<CredCardEntity, Long> {

    public  List<CredCardEntity> findByUserId(Long userId); 

}
```

The UserId attribute is declared like this in the `CredCardEntity`:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "UserId", nullable = false)  
private UserEntity UserId;
```

I have the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'ICredCardRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract
>   java.util.List
>   org.wpattern.frameworks.jsf.primefaces.model.repositories.ICredCardRepository.findByUserId(java.lang.Long)!
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:223)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
>   [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]   at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
>   [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]

Based on this exception I have changed the method `findByUserId` like that:

```
public List<CredCardEntity> findByUserId(UserEntity userId);
```

But it does not work. Could you help me out, please?

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you...

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `UserId` property name to `user`. In this case 'UserId' in your method will be pointed to the `id` property of the `User`.

Also I think `@JoinColumn` is unnecessary here, you can remove it...